# for (ListIterator<E> it = listIterator(); it.hasNext(); ) VS for (ListIterator<E> it = list.listIterator(); it.hasNext(); )

Tags: java, list, iterator, listiterator

Could someone tell me, if the for `(ListIterator<E> it = listIterator(); it.hasNext(); )` part of the code should be instead written as `for (ListIterator<E> it = list.listIterator(); it.hasNext(); )` where `list` is an reference to an instance of ArrayList or LinkedList class? Is both form acceptable and correct? Where should I use one over the other?

```
public int indexOf(E e) {
    for (ListIterator<E> it = listIterator(); it.hasNext(); )
        if (e == null ? it.next() == null : e.equals(it.next()))
            return it.previousIndex();
    // Element not found
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (ListIterator<E> it = listIterator(); it.hasNext(); )
```

This code calls `listIterator()` of myself (`this`) and use its return value. The class where this code is written has higher chance to `List` is implement ed.

```
for (ListIterator<E> it = list.listIterator(); it.hasNext(); )
```

This code calls `listIterator()` of the instance reference to which is stored in `list` and use its return value. This code may appear everywhere to write routines.

Both are acceptable, but whether thay are correct should depend on what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question! I was just wondering if you could provide me with an working example of for (ListIterator<E> it = listIterator(); it.hasNext(); ), I am very confused about how to use it. Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

```
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestIndexOf<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object e){
        for(ListIterator<E> it = listIterator(); it.hasNext();)
            if (e == null ? it.next() == null: e.equals(it.next()))
            return it.previousIndex();
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        TestIndexOf<String> ti = new TestIndexOf<>();
            ti.add("a");
            ti.add("b");
            ti.add("c");
            ti.add("d");

        System.out.format("The index of %s is %d\n", "b", ti.indexOf("b"));
    
    }
}
```